# MDX MTD to get the month to date data

Tags: mdx

Currently i need to show the data which is from the first day of month until the specific date.

```
SUM(MTD([D Time].[calendar].CurrentMember.parent), [Measures].[Wt])
```

I try the code above is shown the first day of month until the end of the month...
Anyone can help to correct my code? Or should i use `PeriodToDate`?

Something like this? :

```
     Sum(
     PeriodsToDate(
         OPENINGPERIOD([D Time].[calendar].CurrentMember), 
         [D Time].[calendar].CurrentMember
      ) , [Measures].[Wt] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the function `.currentmember` then it assumes the hierarchy is being used in either the `WHERE` clause, or `on rows` or `on columns`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].X AS 
    Aggregate
    (

         [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Children(0)
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Order Count]
   ,[Measures].X
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[8].Children} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is it via `OPENINGPERIOD`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].X AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent.Children(0)
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].Y AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        OpeningPeriod
        (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
         ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Parent
        ).Item(0)
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
     ,[Measures].[Internet Order Count]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Order Count]
   ,[Measures].X
   ,[Measures].y
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[8].Children
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[7].Children
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Here is a sample of what this returns:

[image]

Comment: (if you hit the green tick mark then you earn points & it encourages people to help you in the future - so feel free to mark an answer as the answer)